# Can we add a model variable as upper bound for another variable in Pyomo?

Tags: python, variables, pyomo

I am trying to do this in pyomo Concretemodel() but I get and error:

```
 model.Smax = Var( within=PositiveIntegers )
 model.Z = Var(model.T, bounds=(0, model.Smax))


 ValueError: Non-fixed input of type '<class 'pyomo.core.base.var.SimpleVar'>' supplied as variable 
 upper 
 bound - legal types are fixed expressions or variables.parameters
```

How could I change the code to have that upper bound? Or should I used a constraint on the max value for Z[t] instead?

Thanks

Comment: It would be appropriate to set it up as a constraint, not as a bound.

Answer (score 1):

For the upperbound or the lowerbound, you can set it like this:

```
model.P_min = Param(model.J)
model.P_max = Param(model.J)

def Pbounds(model, j):
    return (model.P_min[j], model.P_max[j])
model.P = Var(model.J, bounds=Pbounds, domain=NonNegativeReals)
```